# Encrypting a file in win API

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography

hi I have to write a windows api code that encrypts a file by adding three to each character.

**so I wrote this now its not doing anything ... where i go wronge**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE filein,fileout;

    filein=CreateFile
    (L"d:\\test.txt",GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    fileout=CreateFile
    (L"d:\\test.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    DWORD really; //later this will be used to store how many bytes I succeed to read
    do
    {
        BYTE x[1024];  //the buffer the thing Im using to read in
        ReadFile(filein,x,1024,&really,NULL);

        for(int i=0 ; i<really ; i++)
        {
            x[i]= (x[i]+3) % 256; 
        }

        DWORD really2;
        WriteFile(fileout,x,really,&really2,NULL);

    }while(really==1024);

    CloseHandle(filein);
    CloseHandle(fileout);

    return 0;
}
```

and if Im right how can i know its ok

Comment: Wow, nothing motivates me to help more than being called a moron!

Comment: @Steven Sudit: It's not so bad if thats the moron's name.

Comment: @Kristian: I only asked if it was homework because adding three to each character is not really encryption! Seems like an exercise in writing code to use winapi. I hope you are not offended.

Comment: @Tester101: And yet "Moron" has a valid point. :-)

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Even a blind squirrel finds a nut from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't overwrite a file that's in use.  You will need to use different pathnames for your input and output, and then rename files at the end.

Comment: Or he could read the entire file into memory, then overwrite it.  There are *a lot* of disadvantages in using that method, of course.

Comment: Thanx that work
@Brian can you give me a hint on how to do so ?